# Import with multiple arguments: running python script in flask

Tags: python, html, flask, python-import

I have a python script main.py that takes in two arguments (2 text files)

I'm using MAC OS X
Python 2.7

This runs easily on terminal with:

```
python main.py train.txt sample.txt
```

I have now developed a small front-end using Flask with very minor HTML as follows:

```
  #front.py FLASK
  from flask import Flask, render_template, request, redirect
  app = Flask(__name__)

  @app.route('/')
  def hello_world():
  return render_template('index.html')

  @app.route('/signup', methods = ['POST'])
   def signup():
    email = request.form['email']
    email1 = request.form['email1']
    # command below is just for testing, I wish to implement the same as this would if this would be typed in terminal.
    print("main.py " + email + " " + email1) 
   return redirect('/')

 if __name__ == "__main__":
  app.run()
```

and the HTML

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
   <html>
     <head>
       <title>T</title>
     </head>

     <body>
       <form action="/signup" method="post">
       <input type="text" name="email"></input>
       <input type="text" name="email1"></input>
       <input type="submit" value="Signup"></input>
       </form>
    </body>
  </html>
```

This HTML code is simply using a form to take in the 2 arguments ( I find this easier than JS as I have no experience with that).

I have just written the

```
    print("main.py " + email + " " + email1)
```

command above to test, it's not of any utility for now.

Usage of the parameters:

```
  #main.py

  from filter import Filter
  import sys

  # Get arguments from user
  train = sys.argv[1]
  messages = sys.argv[2]

  # Open files for reading and writing
  train_file = open(train, "rb")
  messages_file = open(messages, "rb")
  predictions_file = open("predictions.txt", "w")

 # Create new filter and train it using the train-file
 f = Filter()
f.train(train_file)

 #filter the messages in messages_file, write results to predictions_file
 f.filter(messages_file, predictions_file)

# Close all the files
 train_file.close()
 messages_file.close()
 predictions_file.close()
```

I wish to now run my script which is main.py via this flask application itself, and want to know how this is possible.

I was using import main with another app decorator say /exec and manually changing the URL to go from 127.0.0.2000 to 127.0.0.2000/exec but this was giving errors as main requires the arguments to be passed.

Sorry if I'm unclear in explaining the problem, please let me know if I can explain anything in a better way to help understand the problem.

Thank you

Comment: Why don't you show the code of main.py?

Comment: I feel it would just add to the length of the post, it's fairly large and is essentially a Bayes Classifier for spam prediction.

Comment: But why can't you just import it and call whatever functions it defines?

Comment: I did try to import it, but it needs 2 text files as parameters. I want the user to enter these filenames or upload the files via the front end of my flask application, the back end would then call the main script as main.py file1.txt file2.txt 

As of now I've only been able to get the file names via the front end and dont know how to call the main script while passing these names as parameters.

Comment: Which is why you should *show the code*. It's not clear what you mean by an import needing parameters. Where does it get them? How does it use them?

Comment: I have added the code as to how the parameters are being used.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to rework this script slightly. You should put all the code that deals with input inside a `name == '__main__'` block as you do in the Flask app, and the rest inside a function that you call from that block:

```
def do_stuff(train, messages):
    # Open files for reading and writing
    train_file = open(train, "rb")
    ...
    predictions_file.close()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    # Get arguments from user
    train = sys.argv[1]
    messages = sys.argv[2]
    do_stuff(train, messages)
```

Now your Flask app can call `main.do_stuff(email, email1)`.

Comment: That works perfectly! Thank you so much :D
A side note, the final file I'm writing into, can I incorporate the output of that file as it is onto my flask application as well? Say after the script is executed and the file is written into, the page now shows the result file on 127.0.0.2000 and then I can redirect back to the start page when I click a button?